# Python: Printing dictionary outside of for loop only prints last value

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, for-loop

I have made some dictionaries as shown below. When printing the dictionary within the for loop it works and prints all the of the values in the CSV column I want it too.

However, when printing StationList outside of the for loop it only prints the last value of the csv where I want it to print all the values. How would I get the dictionary to output all the values when printing it outside the for loop?

```
DictConnections = {} 
StationList = {}


with open('londonconnections.csv', 'r') as csvfile: 
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
for row in reader: 
    Station1 = (row['station1'])
    Station2 = (row['station2'])
    Time = (row['time']) 
                       
    DictConnections[Station1, Station2] = Time
    StationList = Station1
    

   
print(StationList) 

Output: 
13
```

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What do you think `StationList = Station1` does?

Comment: You're reassigning the `StationList` variable each time through the loop, which discards the previous contents.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when you do:

```py
StationList = Station1
```

the variable `StationList` will now point to the current memory position of `Station1`.

### So to resolve the "issue" two possibilities:

1. Put back the print inside the loop.
2. Create a list and add (`append()`) all `Station1` as you iterate over the rows.

For the second possibility you need to create an empty list before the iteration of the rows:

```py
stations = []
```

then inside the loop (where you had put the print before) you append to the list:

```py
stations.append(Station1)
```

Now you can print the list:

```py
print(*stations, sep = "\n")
```